# Multi-Threaded pinging hundreds of hosts solution for fsockopen in php

Tags: php, multithreading, solution, fsockopen

I'm running a website which monitors some servers and there are more servers added daily.

Sadly my current solution is very slow (about 10 seconds loadtime for 31 servers). I'm using fsockopen which checks the IP and port. Because I parse a XML with the entries (host and port) I had to create a function and use this function in the parser so the visitors of the website can see the online or offline status of the server.

My current "checkserver" function looks like this:

```
function checkServer($ip, $port)
{
    $fsockopen = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, 1);
    if (!$fsockopen) 
        return false;

    else return true;
}
```

And in the parser the "if" rule for the server status looks like this:

```
if (checkServer((string)$server->host, (string)$server->port))
    {
        echo "SERVER ONLINE!";
    }
else 
    {
        echo "SERVER OFFLINE!";
    }
```

Where `$server` is every single listed server in the XML `<serverlist></serverlist>` tag.

I already tried to change the timeout of fsockopen from 1 to 0.1 but some servers appear offline then and the loadtime is still at 8-10 seconds.

How could I speedup the loadtime? Could someone please help me with this?.. the project is very important for me. Thank you! I really appreciate every helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest caching. I am not sure how many users will open the page, but if you have multiple users per second opening the page you will have a lot of traffic to handle which on long term could create issues.

You have 2 solutions :

- Using asynchronous events can allow you to do what you wish.T here are some libraries outhere doing this that can help you. I have used none sofar so I can't say which is best.
- Using a library that cheats and uses exec & command lines : https://github.com/oliverde8/PHP-AsynchronousJobs
- Using pthread library, this isn't a library coded in php, so it binaries you need to add to your http://pthreads.org/. You can add another library ontop to make the usage easier
- Finally using javascript, so you open your page, then some ajax calls your php individually for each server & ask status.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I appreciate your time and help!
Many users will open the page, I know that there will be much traffic, that's why I search for a good multi-threaded solution, I'm always looking around how I could build a great solution to handle all the requests from the server. 

I'll take a look on the links, maybe they help me.

I'm always grateful for more tips :)